# Given a 12x12 binary image (only black and white pixels) what is its dimensionality? And how can I define dimensionality of a data space?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, pca, image-recognition, dimensionality-reduction

Suppose I have a grid 12x12 of pixels that can be only black or white. I can't understand if the dimensionality is 2 or 3. I mean... Is dimension given by 12x12 or 12x12x2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some ambiguity in *dimensionality* you ask for. The vector space that your input lies in is $12\times12 = 144$ dimensional. So, if you're going to apply some kind of dimensionality reduction algorithm, e.g. PCA, this is the *dimension*. But, we sometimes tend to refer to *dimension* as the shape of the tensor, which is $2$ in this case. Some libraries might read the image into $12\times12\times3$ tensors, in which the third entry indicates RGB decomposition, even if the image is black and white. In this case, the tensor dimension is $3$.

Comment: Yes, I want to apply a dimensionality reduction but also in this case I don't understand why the dimensionality is **12x12** and not **12x12x2** (no rgb, just black or white).

Comment: Where does that 2 come from? Is it the number of possible choices for a given pixel?

Comment: Yes, supposing that we are talking about rgb pixels the dimensionality could be **12x12x3**... or not?

Comment: Definitely not. {0,1} is your domain, it has nothing to do with dimensionality. In RGB, your domain would be binary numbers with 24-bits, i.e. $2^{24}$ possible values. For dimensionality, you'll consider how many *variables* you have, not their values. In this case, you have $144$, i.e. $x_{1,1},x_{1,2},...x_{12,11},x_{12,12}$